# Page Layout Designer CMS

Tags: php, jquery, layout, content-management-system, concrete5

I am currently working on a content management system to be used by future clients sites. The project is currently in its infancy, and whilst thinking through some of the workings I have come across an issue.

I want the CMS to be very easy to use and edit site content, and add new content with minimal technical knowledge for the end user. What I am struggling with is creating a page designer for the admin backend. It will essentially allow the admin of the site to add new content, whether it be image, text, a twitter feed or some custom HTML. My aim is for it to be similar to the content editor used by Concrete5. I have done research and tried to figure out how they do it, but it has alluded me. Unlike Concrete5 I am hoping mine will just display simple blocks in the editor, rather than editing the full site. The blocks will then be stored in a database individually and then output when the page is requested.

I have experimented with the jQuery UI, using draggable elements and constraining them to a set layout, which seems okay but it is not ideal.

I am flexible to changing the way of doing this and very open to any suggestions you can give.

Comment: You should consider concrete5 further. Granted, it's a pretty complex system, but so are all CMS'. If you can't understand what it's doing, you might have some problems down the road. I think it'd probably be easier to learn c5 configuration (such as using advanced permissions, deleted blocks, etc) than starting from scratch.

Comment: Yeah this is probably what I will do in due course, however I am running on a fairly tight schedule at the minute and just dont have time to do this right now. But yeah I definitely will go ahead and learn how they do it in the not too distant future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want the admin-users to be able to add some sort of widgets to the site. I would take a look at how for instance Kentico CMS is solving this: http://www.kentico.com/Product/All-Features/Content-Management/Widgets. You may download a free demo from http://www.kentico.com/Download-Demo/Trial-Version.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I want. Will take a look! Thanks very much for your fast response :)

Comment: Kentico CMS is written in C#, but I guess you are looking for an alternative or ways to solve this, so hopefully it will help you out :)